# Create own dependency injection annotation

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, annotations

I'm creating a `jar` library and I want users to use DI for access to the library interface.

For example:

Instead of writing this in each class that uses the lib:

```
ApiEntryPoint entry = API.getEntryPoint();
```

I want users to be able to use a field annotation:

```
@ApiEntry  
private ApiEntryPoint entry;
```

I have looked into Dagger and Guice but I don't think they provide a way to create my own DI annotation.

Any tips to get me started would be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a thing you can do in general.  What you could do is provide e.g. a module that `@Provides` an `ApiEntryPoint` that users could install in their Dagger setup.

Comment: Besides declaring your annotation, you'll have to scan classes for it, and modify classbytes to inject bytecode to do `this.entry = API.getEntryPoint()` into the constructor of the class, using a custom classloader or instrumentation. It's a really broad question, and it takes a book to explain it all. If this question is just about annotations and how to use them, you could start by writing a Main class, annotating a field, and having the `main` method list the fields and annotations. Have you seen [the trail on annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html)?

Comment: if you are releasing a library, it is really not your problem how users do DI with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should create your annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface ApiEntry {
    ApiEntry value();
}
```

Afterwards you should create a `producer` in order to return an instance of the bean you want to inject:

```
public class ApiEntryFactory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @Produces
    @ApiEntry
    public ApiEntryPoint getApiEntryPoint(ApiEntryPoint apiEntryPoint) {
        return apiEntryPoint;
    }
}
```

Then, you create your bean:

```
@Named
public class ApiEntryPoint implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Last but not least, you inject your instance where you need it:

```
@Inject
@ApiEntry
private ApiEntryPoint apiEntryPoint;
```

Regarding configuration, you'll need a `beans.xml` file in order to enable CDI. Since you're developing a JAR file, the `beans.xml` file must be in the META-INF directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Any doubts that may arise, you can also look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjdid.html).

Comment: So it is not possible to inject something without the @Inject annotation?

Comment: Nope, since the `@Inject` annotation is what allows the identification of components as being injectable. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html).